# DLL_PROCESS_DETACH only one thread remaining

Tags: multithreading, dll

--- symptoms

When i load my Dll from a subthread of the host app and host app closes, only 1 thread remains when `Dll_PROCESS_DETACH` called. This is bad. It causes memory leaks and the required cleanup can't be done.

When i load my Dll from MAIN thread of the host app and host app closes,
all threads created in Dll are still running when `Dll_PROCESS_DETACH` called.
This is good, because i can do all the cleanup work required.

My `Dll_PROCESS_ATTACH` contains NO code. No thread is created, no API function called.

-- purpose of this Dll, use case

I need a Dll which can run in various host apps where i do not know when
exactly my Dll is loaded and unloaded.

Some of those host appls obviously
load my Dll from within a thread,  e.g. this thread is running a script and the script uses exported functions of my Dll.

The general problem is: When the Dll is first loaded from a subthread of host app, it is not unloaded properly, because all threads seemed to be removed when `Dll_PROCESS_DETACH` called. This just not only causes memory leaks, also it can't do some internal clean up work, stopping threads and doing a final socket connection, used to communicate with a server.

All this works fine, when the Dll is loaded from a main thread (in my test host) or in specific host apps it tested.

Two stack traces of debug sessions of the c++ Dll running in Visual Studio 17.
First is the bad one, where the Dll is loaded froma subthread.

The 2nd is the good one, where the Dll been loaded from main thread.

```
// exit stack Dll  Dll loaded in subthread ; breakpoint in `Dll_PROCESS_DETACH` This is BAD


DllTest.dll!DllTest_app::~DllTest_app() Line 176    C++
    [External Code] 
    DllTest.dll!DllTest_app::destroy() Line 208 C++
    DllTest.dll!DllMain(HINSTANCE__ * hModule, unsigned long ul_reason_for_call, void * lpReserved) Line 43 C++
    [External Code] 
    DllTest_test.exe!exit_or_terminate_process(const unsigned int return_code) Line 130 C++
    DllTest_test.exe!common_exit(const int return_code, const _crt_exit_cleanup_mode cleanup_mode, const _crt_exit_return_mode return_mode) Line 271    C++
    DllTest_test.exe!exit(int return_code) Line 283 C++
    [External Code] 
// exit stack Dll loaded in mainthread; breakpoint in `Dll_PROCESS_DETACH` This is GOOD


DllTest.dll!DllTest_app::~DllTest_app() Line 175    C++
    [External Code] 
    DllTest.dll!DllTest_app::destroy() Line 208 C++
    DllTest.dll!DllMain(HINSTANCE__ * hModule, unsigned long ul_reason_for_call, void * lpReserved) Line 43 C++
    [External Code] 
    DllTest_test.exe!DllTestWrap::Unload(int code, int bdeleteerror) Line 139   C++
    DllTest_test.exe!DllTestWrap::~DllTestWrap() Line 66    C++
    [External Code] 
    DllTest_test.exe!_execute_onexit_table::__l22::<lambda>() Line 198  C++
    DllTest_test.exe!__crt_seh_guarded_call<int>::operator()<void <lambda>(void),int <lambda>(void) & __ptr64,void <lambda>(void) >(__acrt_lock_and_call::__l3::void <lambda>(void) && setup, _execute_onexit_table::__l22::int <lambda>(void) & action, __acrt_lock_and_call::__l4::void <lambda>(void) && cleanup) Line 199   C++
    DllTest_test.exe!__acrt_lock_and_call<int <lambda>(void) >(const __acrt_lock_id lock_id, _execute_onexit_table::__l22::int <lambda>(void) && action) Line 882   C++
    DllTest_test.exe!_execute_onexit_table(_onexit_table_t * table) Line 222    C++
    DllTest_test.exe!common_exit(const int return_code, const _crt_exit_cleanup_mode cleanup_mode, const _crt_exit_return_mode return_mode) Line 211    C++
    DllTest_test.exe!exit(int return_code) Line 283 C++
    [External Code]
```

How to accomplish, that on Dll_PROCESS_DETACH called, all threads created in Dll still running and not terminated, regardless, if Dll is loaded from subthread or mainthread of host app.

Is there something that can be done by compiler- or linker settings, or a workaround ?

Thank you in advance for each hint.

Comment: The destroy function just destroys an object when DLL_PROCESS_DETACH called.
This object is created, when first time an exported function is called. So outside DllMain.
This object does all the jobs to be done in my DLL. It starts several threads, make socket connection and so on. 

The destroy is not destroying the Dll, this is impossible, because the host app is doing this, when calling FreeLibrary.

But is seems, since my object starts thread, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH is called, when ALL threads just be removed, without giving me the chance to clean up.

Comment: The name DllTest_app ins unlucky, sorry. It is just a name of an object created, when an exported function of the DLL is called first time. It is not the DLL itself.
But this object, creates threads, that  need to end in a normal manner. But this is not possible and this is the problem.
Please download a very small sample project from link, where i could reproduce this problem:

Comment: Sample project:
http://www.filedropper.com/testdll2_1

How to use:
create folder c:\debuglib
build project (win64, debug)
Run.
Click on "Load DLL create Thread in DLL"
Click on Unload DLL
In file dllmain.cpp DLL_PROCESS_DETACH is not called!
When you close the app, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH is called
but all threads (dll_test_thread_function) terminated.
This is the problem. 
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like one of the threads in your app calls exit() which leads to calling ExitProcess() API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess

As documented in ExitProcess documentation, it terminates all threads and then calls DllMain() with DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.

Calling ExitProcess can also lead to a deadlock, if the terminated threads hold a mutex which the last thread executing DLL_PROCESS_DETACH tries to acquire.